# C++ overridden function not called

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, dynamic-binding

I am running into an issue where an overloaded function is not called, and the base function is called instead.  I suspect this is related to how things are split between the project files.

In files obj1.h/obj1.cpp I have something like this

```
class obj1{
public:
    void print();
};

void obj1::print(){
    cout << "obj1::print()";
}
```

In files obj2.h/obj2.cpp I have something like this:

```
#include "obj1.h"   
class obj2 : public obj1{
public:
    void print();
};

void obj2::print(){
    cout << "obj2::print()";
}
```

In separate files, I do something like this:

```
#include "obj1.h"   
class obj3{    
public:
    vector<obj1*> objlist;
    void printobjs();
    void addobj(obj1* o);
};

void obj3::printobjs(){
    vector<obj1*>::iterator it;
    for (it=objList.begin(); it < objList.end(); it++)
        (*it)->print();

void obj3::addobj(obj1* o){
    objlist.push_back(o);
}
```

Then in a different file:

```
#include "obj2.h"
obj3 o3;
main(){
    obj2* newobj2;
    newobj2 = new obj2();
    o3.addobj(newobj2);

    o3.printobjs();
```

My issue is that printobjs() results in the obj1.print() being called.  (I have searched around a bit, and read a few dozen posts with overloading issues, but did not see a similar issue)

Can someone point me in the right direction on this?  Thanks!

Comment: The functions need to be `virtual` for what you want.

Answer (score 4):

`print` is not a virtual function, so you are just relying on static dispatch. This will select the function to call based on the static type of the object, which is `obj1`in this case.

You should make `print` virtual:

```
class obj1{
public:
    virtual void print();
};
```

Then if you use C++11 you can mark `obj2::print` as `override` for safety's sake:

```
class obj2 : public obj1{
public:
    void print() override;
};
```

Also note that you never allocate any memory for `newobj2`.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `print()` as virtual to calling obj2::print() for obj2 objects.

```
virtual void print();
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not entirely sure, it is log time since i did c++, but as I remember You should have the vectors contents be classes with pure virtual functions.

That should force it to look up the right method.

There is a stack overflow answer here, which is slightly related:

[Pure Virtual Class and Collections (vector?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394581/pure-virtual-class-and-collections-vector)

Comment: No need for pure virtual functions.

Comment: Thank You - so that is in place. I got enlightened here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained