# Access derived virtual function from base class, good practice?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

Is there a good practice to access a derived virtual function from it's base class?
Here's what I got so far:

```
class A {
public:
    enum class AType{A,B,C,D};   
    AType aType = AType::A;    
    virtual void Do(){}
};

class B : public A {
public:  
    int val = 0;  
    B(int i) {
        aType = AType::B;
        val = i;
    }   
    void Do(){
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::map<std::string, A> bunch;  
    bunch["01"] = B(10);
    bunch["02"] = B(15);
    bunch["03"] = B(80);

    for (auto& [k, b] : bunch){
        switch (b.aType){
        case A::AType::A:
            break;
        case A::AType::B:
            static_cast<B&>(b).Do();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not too happy about using a switch there, any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: a map of `A`s cannot hold `B`s, read about object slicing. Once you fixed that, why do you need the switch? Can't you simply call `b.Do()` ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just call the virtual method Do() regardless of the type? Or am I missing something?

Comment: well, the map is of A type, and when I call do on a B that is in A, it calls A's virtual function instead of B's derived function. I didn't know about slicing, I'm reading, hopefully, I get it right

Comment: This should help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434706/unique-pointer-to-vector-and-polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434706/unique-pointer-to-vector-and-polymorphism)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign a pointer or reference to use polymorphism in C++. If you assign a child class as value, there would be a object slicing. I'd use `std::unique_ptr` than raw pointer like following, which prints out `10 15 80` as excepted.

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>

class A {
public:
    enum class AType { A, B, C, D };
    AType aType = AType::A;
    virtual void Do() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    int val = 0;
    B(int i) {
        aType = AType::B;
        val = i;
    }
    void Do() override {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<A>> bunch;
    bunch["01"] = std::make_unique<B>(10);
    bunch["02"] = std::make_unique<B>(15);
    bunch["03"] = std::make_unique<B>(80);

    for (auto& [k, b] : bunch) {
        b->Do();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @drescherjm, Right, it is no more needed. Good pointing out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never used unique ptr, will B be deleted by itself if it's removed from the map? I also don't need the enums anymore, this is great !

Comment: Yes the smart pointer will handle the freeing of the objects when needed. And yes you most likely don't need the enum.

Answer (score 1):

First, what're showing isn't what I'd call "calling from base class". Otherwise,
calling derived virtual methods from a base class method is one of the main reasons to use virtual functions. The other reason is to call a method via pointer to base class, like you intend to do.

Also, as mentioned above, in:

`bunch["01"] = B(10);`

a temporary object of B type is silently cast (sliced) to object of class A. You should use perhaps map of pointers to A.